# How to create a hbase custom command on jruby?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, jruby

I am new to Hadoop and whole IT itself. I want to know whether I can create a custom `hbase` command similar to already available `scan`, `put` commands.. I have a sample `jruby` script, `client.rb` that outputs the `Row ID` and `Value` by taking `Tablename`, `Family`, `Limit` as input. I can find the ruby scripts of other default commands like `scan.rb`, `put.rb`, in `$HBASE_HOME/src/main/ruby/shell` folder. If I want my custom command's script to be there in that folder and use that command in `hbase` shell, what I have to do?

`hbase 0.94.10`, `Hadoop 1.2.1`, Distribution: `Apache`

Seeking help please...

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I've posted to the hbase developer forum [here](http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/custom-hbase-commands-td4064391.html). If I don't get an answer there, I'm going to give this question a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating the ruby shell command like you've said, you also need to add said command to shell.rb.

See [here](http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/custom-hbase-commands-td4064391.html#a4064394) for more information.